# Sequelize: how can i get the entity i saved with Create

Tags: sequelize.js

I saved an entity in sequelize, but i want to get it back with the promise, but it return undefined.

```
Message.create({

            time: moment.utc().format(),

            isread: false,

            message: data.message,

            messagestatus: 'DELIVERED',

            receiver: data.receiver,

            sender: data.sender,

        }).then(function(message) {

            var m = message;

            var soc = users_socket.find(soc => soc.id === data.receiver);

            soc.emit('disperse message', data);


            console.log(message);

        })
```

why is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
soc.emit('disperse message', data);
```

to

```
soc.emit('disperse message', message);
```

There is not any veriable like data.

Comment: you are right, but even though, message is undefined, and thats the problem

Comment: is this query insert record in to the database ?

Comment: after then comment all the code and console the message.
console.log(message) and check

Comment: ok ok ok, i have seen the issue.....i tried message.dataValues and it gave me back the object